# Error when trying to sort by aggregate function in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have written this query.

```
    sql_query = """
                SELECT title, year, runtime, rating, 
                array_to_string(array_agg(g.name),', ') AS genres,
                trailer, homepage FROM shows AS s
                LEFT JOIN show_genres AS sg
                ON s.id = sg.show_id
                LEFT JOIN genres AS g
                ON g.id = sg.genre_id
                GROUP BY title, year, runtime, rating, trailer, homepage
                ORDER BY
                (CASE WHEN {sort_direction}=0 THEN {sort_by} END) DESC,
                (CASE WHEN {sort_direction}=1 THEN {sort_by} END) ASC
                LIMIT 15
                OFFSET {page_number};
                """
```

The problem is with sorting by column. It's generally works for all the columns except genres.

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "genres" does not exist
LINE 11:                 (CASE WHEN 0=0 THEN "genres" END) DESC,
```

I tried to sort by array_to_string and got same error. 
Also tried to just sort by genres with statement:

```
ORDER BY genres DESC
```

and without CASE statement it works.
What could be the problem?